# iframe - get the size of iframe content which has script tags

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I wanna get the size of an iframe content which has some `<script>` tags. Those `<script>`s render additional content dynamically.

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/ygygy/pen/YzQpdoV?editors=1010.
(You can use the variables `instagram`, `twitter` to render.)

**Is it possible to get that content size?** I don't wanna specific answer, such as using `document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-tweet")`.

Comment: If you embed these social plugins via the scripts the networks provide, then the iframes usually dynamically resize to fit their content already. So in what specific situation / what for, do you need to query the height now? If you don't want to rely on any specific methods the respective SDKs might provide to explicitly query the height or even get notified on changes, then you probably can't do much more than "poll" these iframes for their current height in an interval (or maybe via a MutationObserver.)

Comment: its about same origin policy or CORS. you cannot access content from different origin., like when you using iframe to access content from other sosmed or google or something that not yours.
read this :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: but if the source iframe have same origin. you can use :
`document.getElementById("myFrame").contentWindow.document.getElementById('elmID')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that with `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`
see more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

to get the unknown element wrap it before you write it to the doc with a div with known id like so

`` doc.write(`<div id='my-div'>${instagram}</div>`); ``

and then

`document.getElementsById("my-div").getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: I know but what if the class name is uglified? For example, `a9H2csk`. How can we get the size?

Comment: I mean, your answer is too specific.

Comment: it depends is which framework you use, or you use vanilla
but another option is to select the element by one of the attributes that you know 
for example the href
`document.querySelector(a[href="https://example.org"]);`

Comment: when talking about ref i mean to this
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Hmm I know what you are saying but this is another problem. I think you have to check the codepen link and try to solve the situation.

Comment: the codepen doesn't reflect the problem, im assuming that you get the constant `Instagram` script from another place, and you don't what the data inside,
if so, what you could do is to wrap this content in another div and give it a id or class
like so
```doc.write(`<div id='my-div'>${instagram}</div>`);```

Comment: Thank you Shem Levy, making a div and wrapping the html is a great idea.